# Calculate time difference with 4 date time columns

Tags: calculated-column, calculated-column-formula

I have 4 dates In this format dd/mm/yyyy,hh:mm. 
Date1, Date2, Date3 and Date 4

The formula is: =(Date1+Date2)-(Date3+Date4) the results must be in **hh:mm**

At the moment I have 3 columns,

1. A =TEXT([Date1]+[Date2],"hh:mm")
2. B =TEXT([Date3]+[Date2],"hh:mm")
3. C **=TEXT([A]-[B],"hh:mm")**

I only need one column for this, I've tried putting it together and I get errors.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Create **calculated column** with output type as Date and time. write below formula

```
= TEXT((D1+D2)-(D3+D4),"hh:mm")
```

Comment: I tried that and I get an error that say "Sorry, something went wrong. The formula contains a syntax error or is not supported"

Comment: it's a right answer I tried it that is working properly , just make sure that D1 is your field name ,so based on your mentioned field it should look like  =TEXT((Date1+Date2)-(Date3+Date4),"hh:mm")

Answer (score 0):

Another way to get exact time difference between two dates you can use this formula:

=INT((A-B)*24)&":"&MINUTE(A-B)

EXAMPLE : I have 2 list column, A and B and both are DateTime field. Calculate column is single line of text field.

Values:

A= 11/18/2016 12:10 AM

B= 11/16/2016 12:25 AM

Result= 47:45  (47 hrs and 45 min difference)

Comment: I tried them both again and they worked thank you very much